# JSON validation in dart

Tags: dart

I need to validate if age is bigger then 0 or if email is correct when taking data fromJson. I have no idea how.

this is my model:

```
class User {
  final int age;
  final String email;

  const User(this.age,this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : age = json['age'],
        email = json['email'],

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'age': age,
        'email': email,
      };
}
```

Comment: What are you going to do if the data fails validation ?

Comment: print some error like "email is valid"

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this after you decode your JSON. So in the widget where you make the API call and get JSON, you'd need to check if age > 0 and if the email is valid. You can use the[email validator](https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator) package to validate emails. This is waht the code may look like:

```
var validJson = false;
User newUser = User();
var jsonResponse = FunctionThatReturnsJSON();
newUser = User.fromJson(jsonResponse);

//Validation
if(newUser.age > 0 && EmailValidator.validate(email))
{
 validJson = true;
}
```